# error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class boost::filesystem::path' through '...'

Tags: c++, boost

Errors:

> init.cpp: In function 'bool AppInit2()':
>
> init.cpp:608:83: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class boost::filesystem::path' through '...'
>
> printf("Creating backup of %s -> %s\n", sourceFile, backupFile);
>
> init.cpp:608:83: error: cannot pass objects of non-trivially-copyable type 'class boost::filesystem::path' through '...'
>
> init.cpp:643:76: error: cannot convert 'boost::filesystem::path' to 'const char*' for argument '2' to 'int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)'
>
> sprintf("Old backup deleted: %s\n", file.second);
>
> make: *** [obj/init.o] Error 1
>
> ```
> filesystem::path backupDir = GetDataDir() / "backups";
> if (!filesystem::exists(backupDir))
> {
>     // Always create backup folder to not confuse the operating system's file browser
>     filesystem::create_directories(backupDir);
> }
> nWalletBackups = GetArg("-createwalletbackups", 10);
> nWalletBackups = std::max(0, std::min(10, nWalletBackups));
> if(nWalletBackups > 0)
> {
>     if (filesystem::exists(backupDir))
>     {
>         // Create backup of the wallet
>         std::string dateTimeStr = DateTimeStrFormat(".%Y-%m-%d-%H.%M", GetTime());
>         std::string backupPathStr = backupDir.string();
>         backupPathStr += "/" + strWalletFileName;
>         std::string sourcePathStr = GetDataDir().string();
>         sourcePathStr += "/" + strWalletFileName;
>         boost::filesystem::path sourceFile = sourcePathStr;
>         boost::filesystem::path backupFile = backupPathStr + dateTimeStr;
>         sourceFile.make_preferred();
>         backupFile.make_preferred();
>         try {
>             boost::filesystem::copy_file(sourceFile, backupFile);
>             printf("Creating backup of %s -> %s\n", sourceFile, backupFile);
>         } catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &error) {
>             printf("Failed to create backup %s\n", error.what());
>         }
>         // Keep only the last 10 backups, including the new one of course
>         typedef std::multimap<std::time_t, boost::filesystem::path> folder_set_t;
>         folder_set_t folder_set;
>         boost::filesystem::directory_iterator end_iter;
>         boost::filesystem::path backupFolder = backupDir.string();
>         backupFolder.make_preferred();
>         // Build map of backup files for current(!) wallet sorted by last write time
>         boost::filesystem::path currentFile;
>         for (boost::filesystem::directory_iterator dir_iter(backupFolder); dir_iter != end_iter; ++dir_iter)
>         {
>             // Only check regular files
>             if ( boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(dir_iter->status()))
>             {
>                 currentFile = dir_iter->path().filename();
>                 // Only add the backups for the current wallet, e.g. wallet.dat.*
>                 if(currentFile.string().find(strWalletFileName) != string::npos)
>                 {
>                     folder_set.insert(folder_set_t::value_type(boost::filesystem::last_write_time(dir_iter->path()),
> ```
>
> *dir_iter));
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>               // Loop backward through backup files and keep the N newest ones (1 <= N <= 10)
>               int counter = 0;
>               BOOST_REVERSE_FOREACH(PAIRTYPE(const std::time_t, boost::filesystem::path) file, folder_set)
>               {
>                   counter++;
>                   if (counter > nWalletBackups)
>                   {
>                       // More than nWalletBackups backups: delete oldest one(s)
>                       try {
>                           boost::filesystem::remove(file.second);
>                           sprintf("Old backup deleted: %s\n", file.second);
>                       } catch(boost::filesystem::filesystem_error &error) {
>                           sprintf("Failed to delete backup %s\n", error.what());
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
>           }
>       }

Comment: `prinf()` cannot be used to print instances of `boost::filesystem::path`. You need either to use `std::cout` instead of `printf()`, or extract a `const chat*` from the `boost::filesystem::path` instance.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I put it this way and compiled:
Line 608: std::cout << "Creating backup of %s -> %s\n", sourceFile, backupFile;
Line 643: std::cout << "Old backup deleted: %s\n", file.second;

As soon as the process is finished, I'll test.

Comment: That's not how to use the `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream%, const T&)` operator. There isn't any use of the type placeholders, your statement shoul look like `std::cout << "Creating backup of" <<  sourceFile << "->" << backupFile << '\n';`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The way I put it worked! The file was generated with the date and time parameters normally.

Comment: And you also received the intended output at he terminal? I doublt that. Hint, read about what the _comma operator_ does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I really have not had exits in debug.log ... I'll recompile with your form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friend's @πάνταῥεῖ  answer solved my problem!

```
std::cout << "Creating backup of" << sourceFile << "->" << backupFile << '\n';

std::cout << "Old backup deleted:" << file.second << '\n';
```

Thank you very much!